# Is $\int_\gamma f(z) dz = \int_a^b f(z(t))z'(t) dt$ just a substitution trick?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have read that for a smooth curve $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{C}$ parametrized by $z:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $f$ a continuous function on $\gamma,$ we define the integral of $f$ along the curve as: $\int_\gamma f(z) dz = \int_a^b f(z(t))z'(t) dt.$ Why exactly is this defined in this way? Also is this just a substitution trick? We have ${dz} = z'(t)dt$ so if we substitute $z$ for $z(t)$ this gives us the formula. Is this a valid substitution?

Comment: It is a definition.

Comment: Then wouldn't that be like saying we define 2 + 2 = 1 + 3? It feels kinda weird to me. Why do we define it this way?

Comment: The definition is meant to mimic the line integrals that one usually learns in multi variable calc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Many textbooks define it this way, but...

There is a subtle issue here: why is this definition good? Consider two parametrisations $z_1,z_2$ of the same smooth curve $\gamma$. 
Should $\int_\gamma f(z) dz$ be $ \int_{a_1}^{b_1} f(z_1(t))z_1'(t) dt$ or $ \int_{a_2}^{b_2} f(z_2(t))z_2'(t) dt$?

To use this definition, one needs to prove that the definition is independent of the choice of the parametrisation, which is not trivial (but not too complicated either).

This is exactly why more rigorous textbooks usually introduce the integral as the limit of the Riemann sums. With this definition of $\int_\gamma f(z) dz$ the following Theorem is easy to prove, and implicitly shows the independence of the choice of parametrisation:

**Theorem:** Let $z: [a,b] \to \mathbb C$ be a piecewise smooth parametrisation of $\gamma$ and $f :\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be a continuous function. Then
$$\int_\gamma f(z) dz = \int_a^b f(z(t))z'(t) dt$$

So, to sum it up, there is much more to this "definition" than just a substitution trick.

Comment: Is there a good reason why we want $f$ to be continuous? In general, do line integrals require $f$ to be continuous?

Comment: @伽罗瓦 If $f$ is continuous then it is integrable over $\gamma$. If $f$ is not continuous, it is not clear if the integral is defined.